# how to find the active power supplied by an induction machine

Tags: power-supply, induction-motor

3 phase, 8 pole, 400 volt, 50 hertz induction machine.
supply current 52.8A angle -72.5deg

How do I determine the Active Power supplied by the machine? Is it as simple as (400/root3)*52.8*cos(-72.5)??

Answer (score 0):

> Is it as simple as (400/root3)*52.8*cos(-72.5)?

Xroot3 not /root3